# Why server side code is not firing from JQuery dialog in ASP.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using **Jquery-ui version v1.12.1**

I have a button in my form. Once it click, that will make a **jquery-ui dialog box**. Then I have a one `textbox` and one `asp:button`.

when user click the button, it's not calling to server side code. I don't know why

**Client side code**

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;">
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <input id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-info"  value="Save" />
    <input id="btnLoad" type="button" class="btn btn-info"  value="Load" />

     <%-- SAVE DIALOG  --%>
     <div id="saveDialog" title="Basic dialog">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4">
             <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="File Name"></asp:Label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtFileName" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:center;">
             <asp:Label ID="lblSaveErrorMsg" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
         <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align:center;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveFile" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveFile_Click"/>

         </div>
     </div>
 </div>                   
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
    $('#saveDialog').dialog();
});
```

**Note**

> For testing purpose, I move the button outside of dialog and it was working fine. But when I placed inside the dialog it was not working

I saw this [link](https://relativelypositioned.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/jquery-dialog-aspnet-no-postback/) as well. But for my version there is no alternative code.

I refer this [link too](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/). But I don't how to apply on my code

Comment: When the dialog is displayed, jquery removes all the content from the DOM and re-adds it inside the dialog DIV.  This process can disconnect any events / handlers etc.  Particularly if your form is in an updatepanel and the updatepanel is not part of the dialog.  I don't recall the fix, but this could be the reason.

Comment: @freedomn-m So what is the solution?

Comment: Really? *" I don't recall the fix, "*